# DotNet 6 SignalR Hub Running On Different Port On Localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, single-page-application, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr

When I debug my project the browser show "SPA proxy launch page" with port 7253 the redirect to my application with port 44483.

However, I have noticed that the SignalR Hub is running on port 7253 instead of 44483. I found this problem once I tested with Postman. It return 404 for port 44483 while it work with port 7253.

I'm a bit confuse because my swagger page is working well which is running on port 44483.

Anyone have idea on what is going on?

I refer to this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr-typescript-webpack?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: If you do not redirect through the SPA proxy, run your application directly locally, the port number is 44483? If your program is behaving correctly, this is probably by design of the proxy. Have you tried changing the port number somewhere?